# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting an error:

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module msgsSystemDisplay due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'msgsSystemDisplay' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

and I have no idea why, especially when another module in another `js` and `html` files works totally fine.

```js
(function() {

  var displayApp = angular.module('msgsSystemDisplay', []);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="msgsSystemDisplay">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../stylesheets/index.css' />
  <script src="../javascripts/displayApp.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How are you instantiating you other modules / controllers? Is it the same way like: `angular.module('msgsSystemDisplay', []);` or is the second array parameter not being used like: `angular.module('msgsSystemDisplay');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking the IIFE

```
(function() {

  var displayApp = angular.module('msgsSystemDisplay', []);

}());
```